# Splits, comprehension, capitalise and add FULLSTOP

Tags: python

I need your help. I am trying to write this Python code but I keep failing.

Imagine there is a really rude friend of yours, that always sends emails with all words in capital letters. Your friend also doesn't know how to use a spacebar, so he separates words with the ‘:’ (colon) character. Imagine your friend sends you the message:

```
"HI:HOW:R:U:TODAY:”.
```

- Take this message, as a string. Split it into a list of string words and make each word lowercase using a list comprehension on each element. Read here for information on how to make words lowercase.
- Edit the first and last word (i.e. the first and last element of your list) to capitalise the first letter of the sentence, and add a full stop to the end of the sentence.

Comment: You said you tried, what can you tell us what *did* you try?

Comment: Btw, I'm pretty sure a colon is harder to type than a spacebar

Answer (score 1):

First by using the List comprehension convert your message into list then you can apply your second condition of capitalize the first letter of first and last word and add dot in the end of the message.

```
a='HI:HOW:R:U:TODAY:'
   q=[i.lower() for i in a.split(':')]   #for splitting and lowercase the string
   q=q[:len(q)-1]
   q[0]=q[0][0].capitalize()+q[0][1:]   #capitalize the first letter of first word.
   q[len(q)-1]=q[len(q)-1][0].capitalize()+q[len(q)-1][1:]   #capitalize the first letter of last word.
   q.append('.')     #add fullstop(.) at the end of message.
   print(' '.join(q))
```

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the advice.now i added description as well as comments with the code.